# I couldn't install xampp in port 80. I used netstat to check which program is using port 80 and it showed an unknown application. Attachment available

Tags: apache, xampp, port80

This is what showing when i use netstat command to check which port is using port 80. Also the list of installed application in my server.

Answer (score 0):

Share below command output.

```
netstat -tunlp | grep :80
```

This will show process id.